# .NET (2.0) service can't see network share

Tags: c#, .net, service, network-share

I have a C# .NET service that runs as `DOMAIN\username` on a windows server and it needs to access a network share `\\share\export docs$\`.

If I'm logged into the machine (as `DOMAIN\username`) I can see the share and I have even mapped it to `X:` and tried to use that. I set the path in app.config (and restart the service) and if I use a path on `C:` it works fine but if I try using `\\share\export docs$\` or `X:\` it can't see any of the files I need to access.

I have tried running the service as both a local user and as `DOMAIN\username`

Any ideas what I might be doing wrong?

EDIT: Stacktrace from log:

```
Could not find a part of the path 'X:\200909\11324709\coo.pdf'.
    at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
    at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy)
    at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share)
    at System.Net.Mail.AttachmentBase.SetContentFromFile(String fileName, String mediaType)
```

at System.Net.Mail.Attachment..ctor(String fileName)

Comment: Do you have logs? What error message are you getting when the service tries to access the UNC?

Comment: Check the permissions on the files in the share.  It's possible the user can reach the share but not to its files.

Comment: You have to add this share to access files. In command line, you use `net use`, in Win32 API, `WNetAddConnection3`.

Comment: @Raj: Added the stacktrace
@David: I can read/write all files on the share as the user
@Anton: Having a look at trying to do this in C# now

Comment: UPDATE: So after going the WNetUseConnection route, copying and pasting from the net like crazy, and hacking it in just to see if it would work (which it does), I try it again with the UNC path and it works fine. I suspect someone at the IS department hates me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapped drives in .Net are a bit buggy.  However, this type of situation comes up in questions here quite a bit.  You wold be better to specify the UNC path.

This isn't the exact same question you asked, but this post is relevant to your question and should help you out.

[How do I access a file share programattically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441406/how-do-i-access-a-file-share-programattically)

Comment: Looks promising, thanks. Should probably search a bit harder.

Comment: Don't worry about searching harder.  I mean it's a good idea, but don't kick yourself for not finding it.  The question was phrased differently so it would have been hard to find.  I just happened to have seen that one and it was fresh in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Running your service as Domain\username "should" work.

Are you sure that account has "login as service" rights?