# Access Windows 8 using c#

Tags: c#, windows-8, remote-access, remote-server

I'm writing an application which does stuff like: creating directories, copying files and executing commands.

My application is a server application, and the client is the Windows 8 machine.

I'm trying, for example, to create a directory on my Windows 8 machine, so I use the following command:

```
string outputPath = @"\\" + ipAddress+ "\\C\\NewDir";
Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);
```

Note that C is shared and has permissions.
(My code used to connect to a Windows 7 machine, and it all worked fine...)

At first, it doesn't work, claiming that I entered invalid username and/or password.
After a few try and error attempts, I tried to directly access the remote "C" drive, using Windows' run (\10.0.1.125\C). It, of course, asked for a password, when I entered my credentials and hit "save them", I accessed my remote "C" drive.
Then, when I ran my application again, it also worked, and the directory has been created.

However, it worked before, so I'm guessing there is some sort of "timeout" for saving the credentials for the remote computer.

So I guess my question would be this:
Is there any way to change the connection string in a way which will make it include the credentials embedded within the connection string, so that I won't have to remotely type them each time, and then launch my application?

Something like:

```
string outputPath = @"\\" + userName + ":" passWord + "@" + ipAddress+ "\\C\\NewDir";
Directory.CreateDirectory(outputPath);
```

Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I access a file share programattically](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441406/how-do-i-access-a-file-share-programattically)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the WNetAddConnection2 function to get set your credentials.

You will find on this other post several way to achieve your objective:

[How to provide user name and password when connecting to a network share](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/295538/how-to-provide-user-name-and-password-when-connecting-to-a-network-share)