# How can I log in (WNetAddConnection) to a file share programatically using Qt, C++?

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I wanted to access a file share remotely and I found [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1441406/how-do-i-access-a-file-share-programattically). I haven't tried it, but I think it will work. But I would like to know that is there any way to do this with `Qt` in `C++` (using Visual Studio 2012) ? I copied to here the relevant code from the other post:

```
public static void CopyFile( string from,
                             string shareName,
                             string username,
                             string password )
{
    NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE();
    nr.dwType = ResourceType.RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
    nr.lpLocalName = null;
    nr.lpRemoteName = shareName;
    nr.lpProvider = null;

    int result = WNetAddConnection2( nr,  password,  username, 0 );

    System.IO.File.Copy( from,
                         System.IO.Path.Combine( shareName,
                                                 System.IO.Path.GetFileName( from ) ) );
}
```

Note, that I do not want to copy, just log on. So I need a function like this or an equivalent code:

```
public static void CopyFile( const std::string& shareName,
                             const std::string& username,
                             const std::string& password )
{
    /*
    NETRESOURCE nr = new NETRESOURCE();
    nr.dwType = ResourceType.RESOURCETYPE_DISK;
    nr.lpLocalName = null;
    nr.lpRemoteName = shareName;
    nr.lpProvider = null;

    int result = WNetAddConnection2( nr,  password,  username, 0 );
    */
}
```