# How to access a shared folder as an active directory user

Tags: c#, asp.net, active-directory, iis-6, impersonation

I am running an web application on IIS 6, Windows Server 2003 and it runs under local user IUSR_MachineName.

We have a shared folder, for example `\\server\path` somewhere on our network and only one active directory user has read/write access to it. How can I read/write files from asp.net from/to this folder with this user's active directory credential?

I could change the user under which IIS runs, but I can't (read - not allowed). Now I am reading about impersonation, but any tips on this would be much appreciated...

Edit - I need those basic functionality on the shared folder:

- Directory.Delete
- Directory.Exists
- File.Exists
- File.Delete
- DirectoryInfo.GetFiles
- FileUpload.SaveAs
- ...

Comment: is it possible to change the permissions on the share to allow IUSR_MachineName to read/write?

Comment: Hm... I don't think so, IUSR_MachineName is a local user?

Comment: it could become a domain user. and I believe if you have admin rights to that share you can still add him

Comment: change the Application Pool Identity to the user who is allowed to access that folder.

Comment: Are you using Windows authentication of Forms authentication?

Comment: +1 for @Furqan suggestion. it's definitevely the way to go. Create a dedicated identity for your application, and grant to this identity the right to access the resources.

Comment: Or you can use the solution provided here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1435753/asp-net-access-to-network-share (use net.exe)

Comment: @Furqan - that's it, post it as an answer and I'll accept it, thanks :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the Application Pool Identity to the user who is allowed to access that folder.