# How access UNC path with credentials on ASP.Net Core 2.0?

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-standard, .net-standard-2.0

I am trying to list files on a UNC folder

```
[HttpGet]
public IEnumerable<string> Get()
{            
    var list = Directory.GetFiles(@"\\files.mydomain.com\folder");

    return list;
}
```

But it is giving this Exception

> System.UnauthorizedAccessException: 'Access to the path '\\files.mydomain.com\folder' is denied.'

How can I inform the username and password using C# code on ASP.Net Core 2?

Comment: I tested this, it works on my Windows 10 PC https://stackoverflow.com/a/1435789/194717

Answer (score -5):

Try this.

```
NetworkCredential theNetworkCredential = new NetworkCredential(username, password, domain);

CredentialCache theNetCache = new CredentialCache();

theNetCache.Add(@"\\files.mydomain.com", theNetworkCredential, "Basic", theNetworkCredential);
```

Then do whatever, such as getting a list of folders:

```
string[] theFiles = System.IO.Directory.GetFiles(@"\\files.mydomain.com\folder");
```

Comment: Welcome to SO ! code-only answers might be considered as low quality and hence removed. Can you please elaborate on how this answers the question ?

Comment: I tried many many variations of those code and couldn't get it to work to access a remote share using a "local" user on the remote server.

i.e. trying to access `\\fileserver\share`
with a username of the format `fileserver\localUsername`

Comment: I wanted to create a System.IO.FileStream with this and that might be why it didn't work for. But if you're trying to use a WebRequest this method might still work - e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/a/33377015/990262